# How to pass a simple array data in ngStorage,$localstorage?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

So lets say I want to define an `var array=['a','b','c']`

How do I pass this array into localStorage ?

Should I just simply write `$localStorage.data = array;`?

And also how to check if that array `$localStorage.data` is not empty and not undefined?

Comment: Go to Developer Tools Press F12 --> click Resources Tab --> click on LocalStorage Thats it .. It Helps buddy !!

Comment: An Example :- http://codepen.io/octowombat/pen/eyngH check in developer tools .. and some code example ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass this array into localStorage ?
>   Should I just simply write $localStorage.data = array;?

Yes, you simply put it like this:

```
$localStorage.data = array
```

> And also how to check if that array $localStorage.data is not empty and not undefined?

Check it like simple variable

```
if($localStorage.data){
    console.log('empty');
} else{
    console.log('Data', $localStorage.data);
}
```

[ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

> Right from AngularJS homepage: "Unlike other frameworks, there is no need to [...] wrap the model in accessors methods. Just plain old JavaScript here." Now you can enjoy the same benefit while achieving data persistence with Web Storage.

Comment: but i Thought ngStorage eliminated the need of stringify

Comment: Sorry, you're right :) I've just been working with $window.localStorage but not $localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply store in localstorage as:

```
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(array));
```

and later retrieve it as

```
$scope.data= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

You can check $scope.data by doing

```
console.log($scope.data);
```

Comment: Code pertains the requirement

Comment: Ok and IS  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(array));  same as
$localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(array);

Comment: I haven't used it that way yet but looking at http://cssdeck.com/labs/storing-data-client-side-with-localstorage-and-sessionstorage, I think it is ok to use either one.